# VScode on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (cpp: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory)

Tags: visual-studio-code

In kernel of vscode

> **cpp: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory** The terminal process "/bin/bash '-c',
> '/home/viveksharmavs/anaconda3/bin/cpp -g
> '/home/viveksharmavs/Documents/c++ codes/viveksharma.cpp' -o
> '/home/viveksharmavs/Documents/c++ codes/viveksharma''" failed to
> launch (exit code: 1).

in `launch.json`

```json
    {
        "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/home/viveksharmavs/Documents/c++ codes/a.out",
        "processId": "${workspacefolder}",
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
    {
```

How can I reset settings if needed, or how can I cure this problem? I want to do some C++ coding stuff, but I'm getting these errors.

Comment: Is `g++` installed on your system?

Comment: after  using ,"g++ -v" it show "gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
"